# @FormDataParam throws SEVERE: Missing dependency and doesn't permit to deploy

Tags: java, deployment, upload, dependencies

I'm trying to upload a file, but the use of `@FormDataParam` doesn't permit the application to deploy. The interested code is the following:

```
@POST
@Path("sync")
public String callServletSyncPost (
        @PathParam("tapschema") String tapschema,
        @FormParam("REQUEST") String request,
        @FormParam("LANG") String lang,
        @FormParam("QUERY") String query,
        @FormParam("UPLOAD") String upload,
        //@FormDataParam("file") File fileUpload
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileUpload,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
        )
        throws Exception {
```

I have added to the project the following libraries:

- asm-3.1.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.1.1.jar
- jersey-client-1.2.jar
- jersey-core-1.2.jar
- jersey-json-1.2.jar
- jersey-server-1.2.jar
- jettison-1.1.jar
- jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
- mimepull.jar
- jersey-multipart.jar

I have also tried to add the `jersey-bundle-1.2.jar` library, but the application doesn't deploy.

In the Glassfish 3.1 log page there is the following log:

`The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes: SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String it.inaf.oats.ia2.tap.implementation.TapRestImpl.callServletSyncPost(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.io.File) throws java.lang.Exception at parameter at index 5 SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String it.inaf.oats.ia2.tap.implementation.TapRestImpl.callServletSyncPost(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.io.File) throws java.lang.Exception at parameter at index 5 SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String it.inaf.oats.ia2.tap.implementation.TapRestImpl.callServletSyncPost(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.io.File) throws java.lang.Exception, annotated with POST of resource, class it.inaf.oats.ia2.tap.implementation.TapRestImpl, is not recognized as valid resource method.`

Could someone tell me why the application doesn't deploy and how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue, Pietro?

Answer (score 0):

if your func return smth(f.e. json) you should add

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

and for params

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
```